# Gibbs Free Energy and Equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

In a problem, it was stated that at 25 degrees Celsius, the K(eq)<1. The question than asked whether T(Δ(S)) was larger than, smaller than, or equal to ΔH for this reaction and the equation ΔG = ΔH - TΔS. Given that the reaction is at equilibrium, I assumed that TΔS had to equal ΔH, since ΔG would equal 0 at equilibrium. However, in the answer the instructor stated that ΔG had to be >0 as K<1. This would make ΔH > TΔS.

I don't understand why this is, as I believe that ΔG = 0 when the reaction is at equilibrium. Am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think this system is at equilibrium?

Comment: It is good practice to keep in mind the standard state symbol $^\circ$ as explained in the answer you received. A lot of confusion follows from not differentiating between $\Delta G$ - the difference in free energy between reagents and products in general- and $\Delta G^\circ$ - the difference in free energy between reagents and products when these are in *their standard states* - and $\Delta G = 0$ - the difference in free energy between reagents and products when these are at equilibrium concentrations.

Answer (score 2):

The free energy difference between reactants and products are given as follows when both are in their STANDARD states:

$$\Delta G^\circ = -RT \ln K_\mathrm{eq}$$

If $K_\mathrm{eq}$ is less than one that means $\Delta G^\circ$ is positive and the reaction as written will go to the left until the equilibrium conditions are satisfied. At this time $\Delta G = 0$ and $\Delta H = T\Delta S$.  You seem to understand this well and are confused by the question. The problem seems to me that the the standard state equation wasn't specified or was misread.

Now the problem:  $K \lt 1$ means $\Delta G^\circ = \Delta H^\circ - T\Delta S^\circ \lt 0$ and $\Delta H^\circ \gt T\Delta S^\circ$.  I know this seems crazy because we[I] just said that $\Delta H = T\Delta S$ at equilibrium but remember the standard state values correspond to the reactants before they react to the products before they react in the reverse direction. At equilibrium you have both products and reactants present in the equilibrium concentrations NOT in the standard states. It has taken me 50 years to partially understand this so you are well ahead of the game.